# Custom Search for WordPress Turns Up No Results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, search, advanced-custom-fields

I am creating a searchable image archive the with corresponding information displayed on pages using Advanced Custom Fields. I am developing this on my local host.
I have created a custom search form (searchform.php) as well as a custom search results page (mysearch.php).
The custom search form includes a select menu that is populated by the values of a custom field called 'genre'. While the search form iteself is communicating with the wordpress database metadata table to populate the select menu, the search results page is not turning up any results for the selected value.

This is the code for my search form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php esc_url( home_url( '/' )); ?>">
   <div>
   <input type='hidden' name='page_id' value='979'>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="hidden" value="page" name="post_type">
    <select name="genre">
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $metakey = 'genre';
    $genres = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );
    if ($genres) {
       foreach ($genres as $genre) {
          echo "<option value=\"" . $genre . "\">" . $genre . "</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
  </div>
</form>
```

and the following is the essential of my code for the search results page (with page_id=979):

```
<?php

global $wpdb;

$genres = $_GET['genre'];
if ($genres) {
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

  $args=array(
    'cat' => 23,
    'meta_value' => $genres,
    'paged' => $paged
  );

  $query = new WP_Query($args);
} else {
  get_posts('cat=23');
}

if ($query) { ?>
  <h3>Your Search For <?php echo $genres; ?></h3>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <h3>Recently Added</h3>
  <?php }

if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post();

$genre_search = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'genre', true); ?>
<div class="entry">
  <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
  <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php echo $genre_search; ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">  Read More</a>
</div>
<?php endwhile;  ?>
<?php else : ?>
<p>Sorry no results were found</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

All pages with the custom field 'genre' have a post category ID of 23 (implemented on the pages using the Custom Post Type UI plugin).

The problem seems to be with the search results page rather than the search form since the url generates but does not give any results despite the fact that 150 pages exist with the value selected for the custom field ('genre').

I have been at this for a week and searched many forums, asked the same question on the WordPress forum, but cannot figure out where my mistake(s) occur(s). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: You can't do this: `'meta_value' => $genres`, it doesn't work like that, have a [look here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for what is possible. **Edit:** if you want to use data from wp_postmeta you will need to use `$wpdb` and create your own query with SQL (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

```
     SELECT DISTINCT meta_value 
       FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
      WHERE meta_key = '%s' 
      ORDER 
         BY meta_value ASC
```

?

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**:

This isn't perfect but it will work, and if anyone else runs into the same roadblock it will give you an idea of how to pass the sql query to output results. You can perfect from there. Thank again to FDL for the very helpful indications.

```
<?php

global $wpdb;

$genres = $_GET['genre'];

$querygenres = "
   SELECT wposts.*
   FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
   WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
   AND meta_key = 'Genre'
   AND meta_value LIKE '%" .$genres. "%'
   AND wposts.post_type = 'page'
 ";

 $genrepages = $wpdb->get_results($querygenres, OBJECT)

?>
  <div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

         if ($genrepages):
 foreach ($genrepages as $post):
       setup_postdata($post); ?>

               <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
               <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <?php endforeach;

        endif; ?>
```